# Migrating SQL to Key Value and MapReduce

Tags: mongodb, join, mapreduce, key-value-store, nosql

I have a SQL database with two tables like this:

```
Users
 Id (PK)
 Name

Orders
 Id (PK)
 UserId (FK - User.Id)
 Amount
```

I'd like to move this to a NoSQL (i.e. MongoDb) Key-Value store in the interest of avoiding joins (on very large result sets).

1. Does this structure make sense as-is to be moved to a KV database? If not, should I add another table like User_Orders relating users and orders?

I have a screen that displays Orders in a grid, but I'd also like to display the User name. In SQL I would use a join to pull this from the database.

1. Is there an equivalent in NoSQL (without join) other than querying the database once per Order.UserId to get the related user? If not, how could I apply (Distributed?) Map-Reduce in this instance to accomplish the same goal, assuming my architecture allows me to run multiple front-end and application servers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big change from a relational to a NoSQL database would be *denormalization*. Based on how often the user name changes in your system, you can simply add user name to the `orders` *collection* (a *table* in relational terms).

So, your `orders` collection schema would look like:

```
{"userId":"abc123", "userName": "Some Name", "orderId":"someorderId","amount":153.23}
```

You can use simple `find()` queries to get data about orders and users. If the name were to change, it'd be a *multi-document-update* but then if that does not happen often, its not that bad. For once in a blue-moon updates, denormalization is good as it benefits the reads. Again, this is not a rule of thumb but it is totally up to your use case and design to consider the reads:writes ratio.

If the user name does change very often, and you do not wish to denormalize, then you can always cache the userId to userName map with an appropriate TTL, and look up the ID -> Name in your application layer instead of using the database to impose business constraints.

You wont need map-reduce to just pull orders and users - unless you are doing massive aggregation of data.

Comment: Following this approach, how would I then keep track of all the collections that need to be updated when another changes? Wouldn't I have to modify my code everywhere to also propagate updates to these collections?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to keep that logic in your application layer instead of relying in the database constraints. If you have a read-heavy system, its fairly effective. If it is write heavy (pertaining to that particular attribute), then I definitely would not recommend it.